# Switch master repository

Tags: git, github

I've created a new account at github for a company, and I cloned my own repository to that account.

However, I would like the repository in the company account to be the master (so my account can create pull request to the company in github and not vice versa).

How do I make that happen?

I was thinking about deleting my own repository and then clone the company accounts. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull-Requests are always bidirectional, you can create Pull-Requests from the „Masters“ to the „Childrens“ (and from child to child, and to any other repository in the family-tree).
If you don't like the current view (forked from XYZ), simply delete the Master, the Child will become the new master, then simply fork it again.